# Sudden glitch in else if statements using Pygame and Python in tic-tac-toe?

Tags: python, pygame, tic-tac-toe

We were making tic tac toe and we used `pygame`. We were casually just changing coordinates but for some reason, after coding for the 5th square it stopped working? Does anyone know what's up? Please see below for the code. We were adding lines of code for identifying where the text 'X' or 'O' should go based on what region the moue was clicked in. But, for some reason (what is it?) the last `elif` statement never works, and therefore the x or o never appears. Thanks for taking the time to help.

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
width = 600
height = 600

Board = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.update()
running = True
pygame.draw.lines(Board, (255, 255, 153), False, [(0,200), (300,200), (600,200)], 1)
pygame.draw.lines(Board, (255, 255, 153), False, [(0,400), (300,400), (600,400)], 1)
pygame.draw.lines(Board,(255,255,153), False, [(200, 0), (200,300), (200,600)],1)
pygame.draw.lines(Board,(255,255,153), False, [(400, 0), (400,300), (400,600)],1)
pygame.display.update()

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, (255,255,153))
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text, position):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = position
    Board.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()
def toX(tuple):
    x = tuple[0]
    return x
def toY(tuple):
    y = tuple[1]
    return y
def makeX(pos):
    if toX(pos)<=200 and toY(pos)<=200:
        position = (100, 100)
        message_display(letter, position)
    elif toX(pos)<=400 and toX(pos)>200:
        if toY(pos) <= 200:
            position = (300,100)
            message_display(letter, position)
    elif toX(pos)<=600 and toX(pos)>400:
        if toY(pos) <= 200:
            position = (500,100)
            message_display(letter, position)
    elif toX(pos)<=200:
        if toY(pos) <= 400 and toY(pos) > 200:
            position = (100,300)
            message_display(letter, position)




x = 0
while (running):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if x == 0:
                letter = "X"
                x = 1
            else:
                letter = "O"
                x = 0
            makeX(pos)
```

Comment: "it never works" is not a problem specification.  Please repeat the intro tour, especially [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You haven't provided any trace to support that your clause is "not working".  What are the values of `x` and `y` at the point you have a problem?  Do note that you've covered only 4 or the possible 9 squares, with no handling on the other cases, and nothing for clicking off the board entirely.  This is why you see no help at all from your program.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your `makeX` function, separating out the determination of the *x* and *y* coordinates:

```
def makeX(pos):
    if toX(pos)<=200:
        pos_x = 100
    elif toX(pos) <= 400:
        pos_x = 300
    else:
        pos_x = 500
    if toY(pos) <= 200:
        pos_y = 100
    elif toY(pos) <= 400:
        pos_y = 300
    else:
        pos_y = 500
    message_display(letter, (pos_x, pos_y))
```

I've minimised the changes so it's easier to understand.

With your existing logic, you were only detecting clicks within the first four cells. You could have explicitly extended the logic for the remaining cells, but that is too repetitive and brittle.

Once you're happy with this solution, you need to consider separating the board state from your drawing functions, so you can check for victory and prevent redrawing in the same position.

Answer (score 1):

Akisaat, as you likely realize, this forum isn't set up for your sort of programing-help request. Stack Overflow is more for technical questions by experienced programmers. There are web sites out there geared to your learning level. This site is not.

That having been said, just this once, let's have a look at your code and see where you went wrong.

For most of your squares, the top elif test is catching the X, but the inner Y test only works for a single square, while all other values of Y are being ignored. As a result, once the elif test catches an X value and fails to find a Y value that it can use, control drops out of the if-elif chain and those squares are never handled.

For example, this line catches ALL clicks in the middle column...

> elif toX(pos)<=400 and toX(pos)>200:

..but the nested 'if' test catches ONLY the TOP row. **ALL OTHER squares are lost**
when control drops out of the if-elif chain. You need to test FIRST for a row, then test for all three columns contained in that row. You are only testing for ONE square in any given row.

But I would suggest a different approach, that you put ALL of the row and column tests on a single line. That way you can have separate blocks of code, one for each unique square, without too much nesting going on within any single block of code.

For example:

> > elif toX(pos)<=400 and toX(pos)>200 and toY(pos) < 200: # If Column 1 Row 0 Clicked..
>
> Then do something in that square.

Following the logic of your program will be easier for you if you use comments to name your squares and use print() commands to give reports so you can verify that your code is behaving as planned. You can always go back and remove those lines once your code is proven. Try something like this in your code..

```
  # As an aid, let's identify the squares  for our logic block below
  
  #               |              | 
  #  Square [0,0] | Square [1,0] | Square [2,0]
  #               |              | 
  # --------------------------------------
  #               |              | 
  #  Square [0,1] | Square [1,1] | Square [2,1]
  #               |              | 
  # --------------------------------------
  #               |              | 
  #  Square [0,2] | Square [1,2] | Square [2,2]
  #               |              | 
    
def makeX(pos):    
    
    # Square [0,0]
    if toX(pos)<=200 and toY(pos)<=200: # If the far left column and the top row is Clicked
        print(" Square [0,0] Clicked")
        position = (100, 100)
        message_display(letter, position)

    # Square [1,0]    
    elif toX(pos)<=400 and toX(pos)>200: # If the middle column is clicked
        print(" Column 1 Clicked")
        if toY(pos) <= 200:              # And then if the top Row is clicked
            print(" Row 0 Clicked")
            position = (300,100)
            message_display(letter, position)

    # Square [2,0]         
    elif toX(pos)<=600 and toX(pos)>400 and toY9pos) <= 200: # If the far right Column
        print(" Column 2 Clicked")
        if toY(pos) <= 200:              # And then if the top row is clicked
            print(" Row 0 Clicked")
            position = (500,100)
            message_display(letter, position)
    
    # Square [0,1]
    elif toX(pos)<=200: # If the far left column is clicked
        print(" Column 0 Clicked")
        if toY(pos) <= 400 and toY(pos) > 200: # And then if the middle Row is Clicked
            print(" Row 1 Clicked")
            position = (100,300)
            message_display(letter, position)
```

Doing this to check the logic of your code, and correcting the error I identified earlier should get you well on your way to writing your tick-tac-toe project. Good luck and have fun!